# Why can't Python print an integer and string together without converting it?

Tags: python

```
num = 4
print(num + " other words")
```

In this code, Python would return an error that it can't print a integer and string together like this - I know it's possible to convert the int to a string with str, but why doesn't Python do this automatically?

Comment: `print(num, "other words")`

Comment: Because [it's better to be explicit than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). Python is dynamically **but strongly** typed.

Comment: In which direction would it do an automatic conversion?  Should `1 + "1"` be `2` or `"11"`?

Comment: @jasonharper For some reason Java figured it out and it's pretty consistent behavior. `1 + "1"` would be `11`. A String argument forces all other arguments to be converted to String., which is what people want in 100% cases, when doing `print(String + int)`. `1 + 1` would be `2`, because none of the arguments are String.

Python is pretentious, but ultimately worse designed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

written by [Programiz](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/type-conversion-and-casting#:~:text=In%20Implicit%20type%20conversion%2C%20Python,float)%20to%20avoid%20data%20loss.)

> Type Conversion
>   The process of converting the value of one data type (integer, string, float, etc.) to another data type is called type conversion. Python has two types of type conversion.
>
> 1. Implicit Type Conversion
> 2. Explicit Type Conversion
>
> Implicit Type Conversion
>   In Implicit type conversion, Python automatically converts one data type to another data type. This process doesn't need any user involvement.
>
> Let's see an example where Python promotes the conversion of the lower data type (integer) to the higher data type (float) to avoid data loss.
>
> ```
> num_int = 123
> num_flo = 1.23
>
> num_new = num_int + num_flo
>
> print("datatype of num_int:",type(num_int))
> print("datatype of num_flo:",type(num_flo))
>
> print("Value of num_new:",num_new)
> print("datatype of num_new:",type(num_new))
> ```
>
> When we run the above program, the output will be:
>
> ```
> datatype of num_int: <class 'int'>
> datatype of num_flo: <class 'float'>
>
> Value of num_new: 124.23
> datatype of num_new: <class 'float'>
> ```
>
> In the above program,
>
> We add two variables num_int and num_flo, storing the value in num_new.
>   We will look at the data type of all three objects respectively.
>   In the output, we can see the data type of num_int is an integer while the data type of num_flo is a float.
>   Also, we can see the num_new has a float data type because Python always converts smaller data types to larger data types to avoid the loss of data.
>
> Now, let's try adding a string and an integer, and see how Python deals with it.
>
> Example 2: Addition of string(higher) data type and integer(lower) datatype
>
> ```
> num_int = 123
> num_str = "456"
>
> print("Data type of num_int:",type(num_int))
> print("Data type of num_str:",type(num_str))
>
> print(num_int+num_str)
> ```
>
> When we run the above program, the output will be:
>
> ```
> Data type of num_int: <class 'int'> 
> Data type of num_str: <class 'str'> 
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File "python", line 7, in <module> 
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
> ```
>
> In the above program,
>
> We add two variables num_int and num_str.
>   As we can see from the output, we got TypeError. Python is not able to use Implicit Conversion in such conditions.
>   However, Python has a solution for these types of situations which is known as Explicit Conversion.
>
> Explicit Type Conversion
>   In Explicit Type Conversion, users convert the data type of an object to required data type. We use the predefined functions like int(), float(), str(), etc to perform explicit type conversion.
>
> This type of conversion is also called typecasting because the user casts (changes) the data type of the objects.
>
> Syntax :
>
> ```
> <required_datatype>(expression)
> ```
>
> Typecasting can be done by assigning the required data type function to the expression.
>
> Example 3: Addition of string and integer using explicit conversion
>
> ```
> num_int = 123
> num_str = "456"
>
> print("Data type of num_int:",type(num_int))
> print("Data type of num_str before Type Casting:",type(num_str))
>
> num_str = int(num_str)
> print("Data type of num_str after Type Casting:",type(num_str))
>
> num_sum = num_int + num_str
>
> print("Sum of num_int and num_str:",num_sum)
> print("Data type of the sum:",type(num_sum))
> ```
>
> When we run the above program, the output will be:
>
> ```
> Data type of num_int: <class 'int'>
> Data type of num_str before Type Casting: <class 'str'>
>
> Data type of num_str after Type Casting: <class 'int'>
>
> Sum of num_int and num_str: 579
> Data type of the sum: <class 'int'>
> ```
>
> In the above program,
>
> We add num_str and num_int variable.
>   We converted num_str from string(higher) to integer(lower) type using int() function to perform the addition.
>   After converting num_str to an integer value, Python is able to add these two variables.
>   We got the num_sum value and data type to be an integer.

Comment: You appear to have plagiarised this wholesale from https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/type-conversion-and-casting

Comment: there is a link reference

Comment: ... *reference*? Note that any content you did not author should also be block quoted.

Comment: [Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Answer (score 2):

It can:

```
num = 4
print(f"{num} other words")
```